# Google spreadsheets function for filtering columns

Tags: google-api, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet. In Sheet2 I have some data, and in Sheet3 I want to filter the data in Sheet2. Specifically I want that in Sheet3 will be collected only those columns of Sheet2 that contains a specific variable.

See the image above, this is the Sheet2

[image: Table1]

I want in the Sheet3 only the columns that contain the keyword "Gaetano" in the row 6.
So the resulting table will contain ONLY the column B and C of the Sheet2.

I read a lot about the FILTER function, but I cannot still solve my problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, use filter:

like this:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AkGlO9jJLGO8dFMxN0lDLXR0U0NiQk1JX3ZWOW9jQkE&usp=sharing

A16: =filter(A1:E7,A12:E12)

the true and false values in row 12 cause it to hide colums.

Comment: Nice solution, it works! What if I want to create sheet4 with columns of a different "not gaetano", and sheet5, sheet6, and so on? Do I need to repeat every time the IF statement, or is there a method to automatize the problem? (I'm thinking of a nested IF - FILTER).

Comment: yes, you can nest things. I am not clear on what you want. The google groups forum might be a good place to look. http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!categories/docs/spreadsheets